# MySQL query simple pagination

Tags: php, mysql

here's my data scructure:

```
news
id  date         name
----------------------
2   2015-12-01   news1
3   2015-12-04   news2 
4   2015-12-07   news3 
7   2015-12-08   news4
```

i'm displaying the latest news record (id 7) and want to add navigation buttons for "older" and "newer"

so what's the best method for getting the url for the next older news record (id 4)?
something like `select * from news where [date which is next lower id to current id]`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Query for "newer":

```
select * from news where date > (select date from news where id = X) order by date asc limit 1;
```

Query for "older":

```
select * from news where date < (select date from news where id = X) order by date desc limit 1;
```

Replace X with your target id. I assume the "id" is unique.

Tested on MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit`with range: The first argument is the offset, the second is how many items two return
This will give you the first two records:

```
Select * from news order by id limit 0,2
```

And this the fillowing two:

```
Select * from news order by id limit 2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code parameter_date is date of record 7 in this example

```
//for newer : 
 SELECT * FROM news where date>parameter_date order by date asc limit 1,1;
//for older : 
  SELECT * FROM news where date<parameter_date order by date desc limit 1,1;
```

and if you want do this with id you can use below code parameter_id is your news id

```
//for newer : 
 SELECT * FROM news where date>(select date from news where id=parameter_id) order by date asc limit 1,1;
//for older : 
  SELECT * FROM news where date<(select date from news where id=parameter_id) order by date desc limit 1,1;
```